# Why no explicit transaction handling for JPA read methods like find() and so on

Tags: jpa, transactions, eclipselink

I have an application managed persistence context. Why I don't have to begin and commit a transaction in my code when I call any read method from a JPA EntityManager like find(), refresh(), JPQL-Queries, CrtieriaAPI-Queries and so on?
Finally also Select-Statements need a transaction because of problems like dirty read, non repeatable reads...

Thanks!

Comment: why would you *need* a transaction to read data? It can do those in "auto-commit" mode.

Comment: And how can I prevent the problems like dirty reads and non repeatable reads? I need to set an isolation level. In first place at least "read committed" in the second case "serializable". But isolation levels bound on transactions.

Comment: JPA doesn't let you set transaction isolation. Individual implementations may do. But then you can specify a transaction around a find/query should you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty reads und non repeatable reads will obviously prevented by the same strategy like preventing the lost update problem - with optimistic and pessimistic locks. Isolation levels do not matter in JPA.

```
//no transaction
em.find(foo.class,1,LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_READ);
```

-> Here my own Lock plays no role, because there is no transaction while the lock is to be obtained. My Lock is waste. But ...

```
em.getTransaction.begin();
em.find(foo.class,1,LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_READ);
//some stuff
em.getTransaction.commit();
```

-> There is a period while the lock is to be obtained. The lock makes sense.

Right?